# Strapi not including relational data in response

Tags: strapi

I have a created a relation between multiple table like

- vertical has many users
- tech has many user
- team has and belong many users

so when send request from vertical rest API it doesn't have tech and team in response.
all this data are included in response of users table, but I want this all are also included in individual tables as well.

so I am missing anything in this?
if not then how can I add those in response?

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me explain the relations that you've created:

**You have linked**:

```
Vertical => Users
Tech     => Users
Team     => Users
```

From the above it's clear that you have linked all relations to users collection. So `strapi` will add an `id` in `users` collection to the other relation collections.

so when you do a `find` like below, bookshelf will by default try to fetch & populate all the relations based on the `id` stored in the `users` collection.

```js
// this will fetch the related data also
await strapi.services.users.findOne({id: 1});
```

Now coming to your doubt on how to get the linked data by querying the other collections, you will need to override the find method in controller and write a manual query using `strapi.query('vertical').model` to do a join and get the linked data yourself.

```js
const result = await strapi
  .query('vertical')
  .model.query(qb => {
    qb.join('users', 'users.vertical_id', '=', 'vertical.id');
    qb.join('tech', 'tech.id', '=', 'users.tech_id');
    qb.join('teams_user_relation', 'teams_user_relation.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
    qb.join('teams', 'teams.id', '=', 'teams_user_relation.team_id');
  })
  .fetch();

const fields = result.toJSON();
```

###### Please refer to [Custom Queries](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#custom-queries) in strapi for more information.

Comment: thanks, but in this tech is many to many relation, so user.tech_id will not be in user table.

Comment: But in your question you've stated that `tech` is in `one to many` relation with `users` collection. Only `teams` is in many-to-many relation with `users`

Comment: ya, I mean team data as `Team` has and belongs to many users.

Comment: Alright. Query would be along the similar lines. You would have to do a join on the pivot table/relation table. I've updated my answer with this. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late but I hope this will help others

To return relations you have to add populate query param at the end of your URL

Here is an example to populate associate users to the vertical, replace user with * if you want to return all relations associated with the vertical

```
http://localhost:1337/api/verticals?populate=user
```